# jupyter and notbook installation issue in python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am tyring to install jupyter and notebook in python 3.10 and pip version pip 21.3.
when I run

```
pip install jypyter or
pip install notebook
```

i get following error:

```
Building wheel for pywinpty (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Python\Python 310\python.exe' 'C:\Python\Python 310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\tmpring8cir'
       cwd: C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697
  Complete output (147 lines):
  Running `maturin pep517 build-wheel -i C:\Python\Python 310\python.exe`
     Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.30
     Compiling unicode-xid v0.2.2
     Compiling syn v1.0.80
     Compiling winapi v0.3.9
     Compiling jobserver v0.1.24
     Compiling windows_reader v0.19.0
     Compiling libc v0.2.103
     Compiling windows_quote v0.19.0
     Compiling proc-macro-hack v0.5.19
     Compiling pyo3-build-config v0.14.5
     Compiling const-sha1 v0.2.0
     Compiling once_cell v1.8.0
     Compiling scratch v1.0.0
     Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
     Compiling unicode-width v0.1.9
     Compiling cxxbridge-flags v1.0.56
     Compiling parking_lot_core v0.8.5
     Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
     Compiling unindent v0.1.7
     Compiling smallvec v1.7.0
     Compiling scopeguard v1.1.0
     Compiling either v1.6.1
     Compiling cc v1.0.71
     Compiling instant v0.1.11
     Compiling lock_api v0.4.5
     Compiling windows_gen v0.19.0
     Compiling which v4.2.2
     Compiling link-cplusplus v1.0.5
     Compiling cxx v1.0.56
     Compiling quote v1.0.10
     Compiling pyo3 v0.14.5
     Compiling paste-impl v0.1.18
     Compiling paste v0.1.18
     Compiling winapi-util v0.1.5
     Compiling termcolor v1.1.2
     Compiling parking_lot v0.11.2
     Compiling codespan-reporting v0.11.1
     Compiling cxx-build v1.0.56
     Compiling pyo3-macros-backend v0.14.5
     Compiling windows_macros v0.19.0
     Compiling indoc-impl v0.3.6
     Compiling cxxbridge-macro v1.0.56
     Compiling indoc v0.3.6
     Compiling pyo3-macros v0.14.5
     Compiling windows v0.19.0
     Compiling pywinpty_findlib v0.3.0 (C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\local_dependencies\pywinpty_findlib)
     Compiling pywinpty v1.1.4 (C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697)
  error: failed to run custom build command for `pywinpty v1.1.4 (C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697)`

  Caused by:
    process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\target\release\build\pywinpty-fe97273faa1e7b8a\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
    --- stdout
    cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/lib.rs
    cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/native.rs
    cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/csrc
    cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/
    Windows major version: 10
    Windows build number: 19041
    ConPTY enabled: 1
    cargo:CXXBRIDGE_PREFIX=pywinpty
    cargo:CXXBRIDGE_LINKS=winpty
    cargo:CXXBRIDGE_DIR0=C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\target\release\build\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\out\cxxbridge\include
    cargo:CXXBRIDGE_DIR1=C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\target\release\build\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\out\cxxbridge\crate
    cargo:CXXBRIDGE_DIR2=C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\include
    cargo:CXXBRIDGE_DIR3=C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697
    TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
    OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
    HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
    CXX_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
    CXX_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
    HOST_CXX = None
    CXX = None
    CXXFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
    CXXFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
    HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
    CXXFLAGS = None
    CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
    CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
    DEBUG = Some("false")
    CXX_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
    CXX_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
    HOST_CXX = None
    CXX = None
    CXXFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
    CXXFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
    HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
    CXXFLAGS = None
    CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
    CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
    CXX_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
    CXX_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
    HOST_CXX = None
    CXX = None
    CXXFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
    CXXFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
    HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
    CXXFLAGS = None
    CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
    CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
    running: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-O2" "-Brepro" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\crate" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697" "/EHsc" "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" "-DENABLE_WINPTY=0" "-DENABLE_CONPTY=1" "-DDEBUG=0" "-FoC:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\src/csrc/wrapper.o" "-c" "src/csrc/wrapper.cpp"
    running: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-O2" "-Brepro" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\crate" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697" "/EHsc" "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" "-DENABLE_WINPTY=0" "-DENABLE_CONPTY=1" "-DDEBUG=0" "-FoC:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\sources\\pywinpty\\src\\native.rs.o" "-c" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\sources\\pywinpty\\src\\native.rs.cc"
    running: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-O2" "-Brepro" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\crate" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697" "/EHsc" "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" "-DENABLE_WINPTY=0" "-DENABLE_CONPTY=1" "-DDEBUG=0" "-FoC:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\src/csrc/base.o" "-c" "src/csrc/base.cpp"
    running: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-O2" "-Brepro" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\crate" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697" "/EHsc" "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" "-DENABLE_WINPTY=0" "-DENABLE_CONPTY=1" "-DDEBUG=0" "-FoC:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\src/csrc/winpty_common.o" "-c" "src/csrc/winpty_common.cpp"
    running: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-O2" "-Brepro" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\crate" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697" "/EHsc" "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" "-DENABLE_WINPTY=0" "-DENABLE_CONPTY=1" "-DDEBUG=0" "-FoC:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\src/csrc/pty.o" "-c" "src/csrc/pty.cpp"
    running: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-O2" "-Brepro" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\crate" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697" "/EHsc" "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" "-DENABLE_WINPTY=0" "-DENABLE_CONPTY=1" "-DDEBUG=0" "-FoC:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\src/csrc/StackWalker.o" "-c" "src/csrc/StackWalker.cpp"
    running: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-O2" "-Brepro" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\crate" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697" "/EHsc" "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" "-DENABLE_WINPTY=0" "-DENABLE_CONPTY=1" "-DDEBUG=0" "-FoC:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\src/csrc/conpty_common.o" "-c" "src/csrc/conpty_common.cpp"
    wrapper.cpp
    native.rs.cc
    winpty_common.cpp
    pty.cpp
    base.cpp
    StackWalker.cpp
    conpty_common.cpp
    C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\include\winpty_common.h(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winpty.h': No such file or directory
    exit code: 2
    exit code: 0
    C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\include\winpty_common.h(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winpty.h': No such file or directory
    exit code: 2
    C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\include\winpty_common.h(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winpty.h': No such file or directory
    exit code: 2
    C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\include\winpty_common.h(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winpty.h': No such file or directory
    exit code: 2
    exit code: 0
    exit code: 0

    --- stderr

    CXX include path:
      C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\target\release\build\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\out\cxxbridge\include
      C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\target\release\build\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\out\cxxbridge\crate
      C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\include
      C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-46ljjod1\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697


    error occurred: Command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-O2" "-Brepro" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\crate" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\include" "-I" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697" "/EHsc" "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" "-DENABLE_WINPTY=0" "-DENABLE_CONPTY=1" "-DDEBUG=0" "-FoC:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\sources\\pywinpty\\src\\native.rs.o" "-c" "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-46ljjod1\\pywinpty_9b5ecf5b3b95422b9ddb454158a5c697\\target\\release\\build\\pywinpty-e861041a9b402f09\\out\\cxxbridge\\sources\\pywinpty\\src\\native.rs.cc" with args "cl.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 2).


  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
  error: build failed
  ðŸ’¥ maturin failed
    Caused by: Failed to build a native library through cargo
    Caused by: Cargo build finished with "exit code: 101": `cargo rustc --message-format json --manifest-path Cargo.toml --release --lib --`
  ðŸ\x8d¹ Building a mixed python/rust project
  ðŸ”— Found pyo3 bindings
  ðŸ\x90\x8d Found CPython 3.10 at C:\Python\Python 310\python.exe
  Error: command ['maturin', 'pep517', 'build-wheel', '-i', 'C:\\Python\\Python 310\\python.exe'] returned non-zero exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pywinpty
Failed to build pywinpty
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pywinpty, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

wheel and pywinpty is install correctly, rust is also installed and in the path. I installed microsoft visual studio and all the possible component from their. not sure what should be done from here.

Please help...

Comment: IMHO python10 is not quite ready for primetime yet and many libraries need to still catch up.

Comment: so your suggestion is to degrade the python version correct.

Comment: Yes, I ran into a problem attempting to install torch with python 3.10 and ended up going back to 3.8 for now (as that was what I also had installed)

Comment: i shifted to 3.9,all good now.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like python 3.10 is not ready to use. me degraded my python to 3.9, and it works fine now.